# Why to count integers that are relatively prime to their euler function?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $N(x)$ be the number of positive integers $n\leq x$ such that $\gcd(n,\phi(n))=1$. Here $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function.
A theorem of Erdos from 1948 says that
$$
N(x) \sim \frac{e^{-C_0} x}{\log\log\log x},\quad x\to \infty,
$$
where $C_0$ is the Euler constant. See also Theorem 11.23 in Montgomery-Vaughan's "Multiplicative number theory". Erdos quotes a result of Szele saying that these numbers are exactly those $n$ for which there is exactly one abstract group of order $n$.

My question is whether there is a deeper, or more enlightening, reason to count such integers?

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A003277 and references there.

Comment: Because they are there?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson - The question asks for deeper reasons :)

Comment: In general, mathematicians count things because that's what they do.  No deeper reason is really required.  The fact that in this case there is a connection to group theory, as well as to Carmichael numbers, is a bonus.

Comment: But there are infinitely many things to count. One usually has a good reason to count one thing and not the other. BTW I see that this site counts how many characters left...

Answer (score 5):

If $G$ is a group of order $n$ with $gcd(n,\phi(n))=1$, then $G$ is cyclic. Conversely, if
$n$ is an integer, such that every group of order $n$ is cyclic, then $gcd(n,\phi(n))=1$.
So, counting these numbers is  certainly interesting in group theory.

Also nice (perhaps) is, that the the number of integers in $[1,n]$, coprime to $\phi(n)$ counts the number 
of incongruent primitive roots modulo $n$ , provided $n$ has a primitive root, i.e., the group
$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\ast}$ is cyclic. Of course, this number is $\phi(\phi(n))$.